# How to test install tracking for IOS on Google Analytics

Tags: ios, google-analytics

Is there a way by which we can test if the install tracking gets fired on Google Analytics for IOS ? I have followed this link for attributing instals for iOS but even this does not detail out on how to test this.

Any pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: check the real-time reports on the Google Analytics website.  assuming that the Google Analytics application account was created more then 48 hours ago data should show up there as soon as you add it to your application.

Comment: Thanks Dalm for the reply.. but seems like I was not able to convey the problem properly.. the issue that i am facing is as how to actually check from which campaign source is the user is actually coming from..? And also since I have not pushed the build to production yet.. how can we test it on the dev build.. Lemme know if something is still not clear